# Execute method for each object in generic list using lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm still new to lambdas and find it hard to find out specific features for it, but is it possible to execute a method for each object in a generic list? Similar to how the ConvertAll works, but instead of converting, actually calling a method.

```
public class Mouse()
{
    public void Squeak()
    {
    }
}

List<Mouse> mice = new List<Mouse>();

mice.Add(new Mouse());
mice.Add(new Mouse());
```

How do you call the method Squeak for each mouse?

```
mice.???(m => m.Squeak());
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using `List<T>.ForEach()` method ([see MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwabdf9z.aspx)):

```
mice.ForEach(m => m.Squeak());
```

PS: What is fun that answer is in your question:

> How do you call the method Squeak **for each** mouse?

Answer (score 3):

Please don't use `List<T>.ForEach`. It looks like a sequence operator. Sequence operators shouldn't have side effects. You're using something that looks like a sequence operator solely for its side effects. Instead, just use a plain-old boring loop:

```
foreach(var mouse in mice) {
    mouse.Squeak();
}
```

Eric Lippert has a fabulous article related to this topic: [`foreach` vs. `ForEach`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx).